# Do MPI Datatypes of Send/Receive Have to Match?

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to determine what parameters of a sending operation and receiving operation must match for a message to be passed.

I understand that a receiving operation must match (or encompass) the source of the message, the tag and the communicator. However, is it required for the datatype to be matching?

E.g. could I match a send from rank 0:

```
MPI_Send (send_buffer, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

with the receiving operation on rank 1:

```
MPI_Recv (recv_buffer, 4, MPI_BYTE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status);
```

Particularly as the sending 'count' is less than the receiving count, which I am aware is valid for MPI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is yes, datatypes must match, but there are some caveats.

When using primitive MPI datatypes such as `MPI_INT` and `MPI_FLOAT`, the types must be identical. The only exception is `MPI_PACKED`, which can match any other type.

When using derived datatypes (a.k.a. user-defined datatypes), things get slightly more complicated. A general MPI datatype consists of two things: a **type signature**, which defines the basic language datatypes that make up the derived datatype, and a series of byte **displacements**, which define where those basic elements reside in memory. The combination of both sequences is called the **type map** of the datatype. The primitive MPI datatypes are particular cases of such general datatypes having a single basic datatype in the type signature with a displacement of 0, e.g. `MPI_INT` has the following type map: `{ (int, 0) }`. For a Send and Receive operation to match, the *type signature* must be the same on both sides, but the *displacements* can vary. E.g. the sender might send a single `MPI_Type_contiguous` object consisting of 3 `MPI_FLOAT`s, but the receiver can receive this as an `MPI_Type_indexed` type of 3 `MPI_FLOAT`s with arbitrary displacements. The sender might also supply an array of 3 `MPI_FLOAT` elements, e.g. `MPI_Send(buf, 3, MPI_FLOAT, ...)` and this would still result in the same type signature.

I should emphasize that the type signature consists of basic datatypes only. Whether the user-defined datatype was created directly from primitive MPI types or other user-defined datatypes (or a mixture of thereof) is irrelevant.

Example: the sender defines an `MPI_Type_struct` consisting of 3 `MPI_INT`s and 2 `MPI_FLOAT`s. The receiver defines an `MPI_Type_contiguous` consisting of 3 `MPI_INT`s (let's call this type `A`), another `MPI_Type_contiguous` of 2 `MPI_FLOAT`s (type `B`), and then an `MPI_Type_struct` consisting of 1 `A` and 1 `B`. These two datatypes will match, since ultimately they're both 3 `int`s followed by 2 `float`s.