# MPI_sendrecv Derived Data Types

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I need to send non-contiguous data from one process to a contiguous location on another process (in the C programming language). I've decided to use MPI derived data types, and have managed to define it successfully to match the non-contiguous data I need to send (so the send derived data type).

My question is, when I send a derived datatype (of non-contiguous data), is it received on the other end as non-contiguous data? How can I make it contiguous?

I've tried a couple of things, but I'm not even sure how this all works and so I'm not sure I can articulate my results correctly.

Would anyone be kind enough to shed light on how this works and preferably in the context of MPI_Sendrecv()?

The basic idea is to send non-contiguous data to a contiguous location and, actually, to the same array (just on another process).

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do MPI Datatypes of Send/Receive Have to Match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424720/do-mpi-datatypes-of-send-receive-have-to-match)

Comment: Not really. I had seen that question before posting and it is in the context of MPI_Send and MPI_Recv.

Comment: The answer is exactly the same either way; the way MPI handles derived data types and data matching is the same across all communications functions.

Comment: I've removed the one line which might make someone perceive them to be the same question. I think you should be satisfied now.